# Is Zentyal an official Ubuntu derivative?

Tags: canonical, derivatives

I notice [here](http://blog.canonical.com/2012/06/25/helping-zentyal-offer-an-open-source-alternative-for-small-businesses/) that Canonical has partnered with Zentyal - does that make them an official derivative?

Comment: Just for clarification, what do you mean by "official"?  Official by what standard?

Comment: @inkblend: like lubuntu, kubuntu etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

although we (Zentyal) are Canonical partners to include official Ubuntu support for our customers, we are not currently an official Ubuntu derivative.

For any kind of questions you can use our forums (forum.zentyal.org). We are also attending to the UDS-r where you can meet us in person and ask us directly.

Answer (score 6):

Zentyal is a distribution which provides "server to small and medium sized Business (SMB)". It is based on Ubuntu. ***But, it is not an official Ubuntu derivative like Kubuntu, Xubuntu etc***. The [officially recognized Ubuntu derivatives are listed here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives#Official_editions)

These includes the following distributions:

- [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org)
- [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org)
- [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.org)
- [Mythbuntu](http://mythbuntu.org)
- [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org)
- [Edubuntu](http://edubuntu.org)

We can recognize an official derivative. An official derivative should

- have a `distroname-desktop` package which can be installed in an Standard Ubuntu installation. such as `kubuntu-desktop`
- Another one is, All official distributions uses the same repository as the main Ubuntu.

But, Zentyal uses their customized repositories [as listed here](http://trac.zentyal.org/wiki/Document/Announcement/3.0).

Another important point to notice is, As being an independent company Canonical can co-operate on another project and as far as I know, that doesn't make the project an Official one. Also, To be recognized as an official derivative the project need to significantly contribute to the main Ubuntu project.